# How to transfer files to Windows Server through rdp?

Tags: networking, server, windows, remote-desktop, remote

I am using Ubuntu, and have tested a lot of rdp clients, right now I am using "Remmina RDC". As a web developer I, need to transfer files to the server "Windows Server" and vice versa. I am new to Ubuntu, so I need help! Best option for me is a Windows-like `mstsc` client, but with some other options. please...

The server is not in the same localhost!

Comment: Does it need to be rdp? Any particular reason not to use windows shares and samba?

Comment: Yes, becouse Admin's doesent want to give windows share!

Comment: Aaa.... and the server is not in the same localhost

Comment: OK, please [edit] your question and add that detail as well as any other special requirements you might have.

Comment: You don't: rdp isn't a file transfer protocol.

Comment: See http://www.7tutorials.com/connecting-windows-remote-desktop-ubuntu

Comment: See http://d2bm3ljpacyxu8.cloudfront.net/width/470/crop/0,0,470x537/i1130.photobucket.com/albums/m524/ps8437/rdp_new_preference.jpg the last check box at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've not already tried it, there's ***`freerdp-x11`*** client.

#### Installation:

```
sudo apt-get install freerdp-x11
```

#### Documented Description:

> ```
> RDP client for Windows Terminal Services
> ```
>
> FreeRDP is a client for Windows Terminal Services implementing the 
>     Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP).
>
> Currently, the following Windows Versions are supported:
>
> - Windows NT Server
> - Windows 2000 Terminal Server
> - Windows XP
> - Windows 2003 Server
> - Windows Vista
> - Windows 2008 Server
> - Windows 7
>
> This package contains the X11 based client.

Homepage: http://www.freerdp.com